# What are the best practices for separating concerns with Angular and Express?

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack

*I feel like both Express' and any MEAN stack tutorials gloss over this, so I decided to ask here.*

*See also these similar SO posts:*
[Why would one want to use Express instead of AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700334/why-would-one-want-to-use-express-instead-of-angularjs)
[Angular and Express routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860899/angular-and-express-routing)

Using plain HTML with Angular directives/attributes as the view engine in Express, what's the best practice for rendering page partials in a single layout template with regards to routes?

How do you do this with HTML/Angular as your view engine? 
In Jade, you'd do something like `block content`.

Do you use the Angular Router, `ng-view` and use directives? 
If so, what's the point of Express? Just a server? Why not just use Connect?

*P.S. If you're wondering about Jade or EJS, I'm just learning Express, and Angular, so I'm trying to keep language abstractions to a minimum.*

I guess my confusion originates from the overlaps between Express and Angular in regards to templating and routing, but Express focuses on the server-side, and Angular, the client. For someone just learning these, it's tough to know how to implement when everything is so wide open.

I'm looking for detailed, **specific implementation code examples** that use best practices when it comes to separation of concerns. Seeing it and having it explained in context is how I learn best from others.

Answer (score 1):

Check out angular-blocks if you want jade-like blocks:

https://github.com/wmluke/angular-blocks

Comment: Not so much looking for blocks. I'm more looking for single page layout markup, dynamically loading in a partial based on routes. You can do this with just Angular with routes and ng-view, but then Express seems pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that Angular and YOUR_SERVER is generally irrelevant. It's a matter of "where do my files go". As single-page application suggests, it is a single static route. I'm sure Connect would handle this just fine, but the server portion of your application likely has more concerns than simply serving a static page. Authentication, business logic, API routes and other concerns come into the picture at some point, so Express (and its ecosystem) makes a lot of sense.

Your single-page application will definitely have its own routes. These are *unrelated* to your servers routes, which will include the static route to the Angular application page, and also any routing for API calls that the Angular app will be making.

It's important to understand that you are *writing two distinct and separate applications, connect via an API*. The fact that your Node server is delivering the static HTML and JS is, for the most part, coincidental. The Angular application should be considered, and developed, in an isolated, decoupled way for best results.

Comment: Great points all around, but could you be more specific as far as implementation guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Express and angular serve totally different purposes.

In most MEAN-like stacs situation (for example just express-angular), express acts as server PLUS **API provider**.

You use app.get('/') with any **server side** templating like jade (just to have cleaner html files...), then You use app.get('/partial/:name') to handle all partials with same template language.

then, You use app.get('/api/anyapi1'), app.get('/api/anyapi2') to provide whole api to angular - no matter what it will be - some mongo or postgres handling, or just Your static json files.

In new express4 You can also create dedicated api route with:

```
var api = express.Router();

api.get('/somget', function(req, res) {
    res.send('some json');
});

// init api route. all api routes will begin with /api 
//(like above api.get will be at /api/somget)
app.use('/api', api);
```

You can also deal with sessions and authorization on express side, and whole awful lot of stuff, that shouldnt or cant be done on client side.

Hope it helped.

EDIT: speaking shortly: express is backend with http server, other services and api, and angular is whole frontend which consumes what backends provides.

Having such separation You can even provide that backend api to others, or build different services on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the MEAN stack puts an emphasis on making most of your logic on the front end. Your express server will act as a mule to save, read, validate, and delete data based on the get and post request you make from the front end.

The idea is to have all your front end code in a public folder of your express app.

```
     `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
```

Then simply make a route that renders the index file as such

```
     `app.get('/',function(req,res){
            res.render('index')
       })`
```

With this in mind you may we wondering if there is a solution that can generate an api for you so that you just name your models and the rest is done via angularjs services. There is.. http://loopback.io/  just name your models, relationships and restrictions. It will generate an enteprise level api for you to play with.

For a complete working example on how routing is done and how to model your app check out this tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-nodejs-polling-app/

Comment: If I'm just serving static files, including Angular templates, what's the value in Express?

Comment: flexibility in terms of routing, session control, and data access that can be used in all platforms via REST.